# print selected month date from 1 to 25 and previous month 26 to end of month date in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**@project_site.attendance_month.strftime("%m").to_i)**
this return selected month integer in rails.
and prints selected month date from 1 to end of month date.

e.g-
if **@project_site.attendance_month.strftime("%m").to_i)** value is equal to 1, it prints from 1 to 31 date.

now i want when `@project_site.attendance_month.strftime("%m").to_i)` value is 1, i want to print only 1 to 25 of selected month and, 26 to end_of_date from previous month of selected month.

my current code-

```
<% (1..(Time.days_in_month @project_site.attendance_month.strftime("%m").to_i)).each do |date| %>
 <th class="text-center"><%= date %></th>
<% end %>
```

Example:

```
<% (1..(Time.days_in_month 01)).each do |date| %>
 <th class="text-center"><%= date %></th>
<% end %>
```

it will print 1 to 31 now date of January, now i only want to print 1-25 in January date and 26 to 31 date form December. with the help of this loop.

Comment: Its difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve as you're focusing to much on the nitty gritty details and not telling us exactly what the desired out is. Can you give us an example of dates and what you expect the output to be? This code is also really smelly as this is far to much logic in the view.

Comment: @max, added example for better clarification.

Comment: Do you ALWAYS want to switch at day 25 to the next month?

Comment: @Chiperific, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell me if this is the correct interpretation.

Right now, you get something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    ...
    <th>31</th>
 <tr>
<table>
```

And instead you want something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>26</th> <-- December dates: 26 through end of month
    <th>27</th>
    <th>28</th>
    <th>29</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>31</th>
    <th>1</th> <-- January dates: 1 through 25
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    ...
    <th>26</th>
 <tr>
<table>
```

If this is correct, I'd suggest actually building an array of dates:

```
[2020-12-26, 2020-12-27, 2020-12-28, 2020-12-29, ... 2020-01-01, 2020-01-02, 2020-01-03, 2020-01-04, ... 2020-01-25]
```

This way we don't have to worry about leap years, crossing over years, etc. Ruby will handle that for us.

So, we want to:

1. Figure out if today's date is before or after the 25th of the current month.

- If today's date is <= 25, pull previous month's days 26 through the end && this month's days 1 through 25
- If today's date is > 25, pull this month's days 26 through the end && next months days 1 through 25

2. Put the dates into an array we can use in the view:

*(I'm assuming `@project_site.attendance_month` is a full date object, not just a month)*

```
class ProjectSite
  attr_accessor :attendance_month
  # ...

  def attendance_date_array
    if attendance_month.day <= 25
      first_month = attendance_month.beginning_of_month - 1.day
      start_day = Date.new(first_month.year, first_month.month, 26)
      end_day = Date.new(attendance_month.year, attendance_month.month, 25)
    else
      start_day = Date.new(attendance_month.year, attendance_month.month, 26)
      second_month = attendance_month.end_of_month + 1.day
      end_day = Date.new(second_month.year, second_month.month, 25)
    end

    ary = []
    (start_day..end_day).each do |d|
      ary << d
    end
    ary
  end
end
```

This function will return something like this:

`[Mon, 26 Oct 2020, Tue, 27 Oct 2020, Wed, 28 Oct 2020, Thu, 29 Oct 2020, Fri, 30 Oct 2020, Sat, 31 Oct 2020, Sun, 01 Nov 2020, Mon, 02 Nov 2020, Tue, 03 Nov 2020, Wed, 04 Nov 2020, Thu, 05 Nov 2020, Fri, 06 Nov 2020, Sat, 07 Nov 2020, Sun, 08 Nov 2020, Mon, 09 Nov 2020, Tue, 10 Nov 2020, Wed, 11 Nov 2020, Thu, 12 Nov 2020, Fri, 13 Nov 2020, Sat, 14 Nov 2020, Sun, 15 Nov 2020, Mon, 16 Nov 2020, Tue, 17 Nov 2020, Wed, 18 Nov 2020, Thu, 19 Nov 2020, Fri, 20 Nov 2020, Sat, 21 Nov 2020, Sun, 22 Nov 2020, Mon, 23 Nov 2020, Tue, 24 Nov 2020, Wed, 25 Nov 2020]`

Which you can iterate over in your view:

```
<% @project_site.attendance_date_array.each do |date| %>
 <th class="text-center"><%= date.day %></th>
<% end %>
```